# ViewFlipper stops flipping when device's lights gets off

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `ViewFlipper` to flip two images. one image is a small heart and another is a big heart and they are flipping continuously so that it looks like heart is throbbing.

everything works well except one thing

when the `Activity` containing `ViewFlipper` is on the front and the `ViewFlipper` is flipping once i called the `startFlippling` , and after a while if my device's light gets dim and then turned off and if i press the home/power button immediately the `ViewFlipper` stops flipping. in this case no `onResume` or `onPause` gets called.

moreover when the device's light gets turned off and after a while if i press power button and entered my password to unlock the screen , then the `ViewFlipper` is working fine.

here is my layout code  , i have set the `autoStart` to `false` because based on some event 
i am calling `startFlipping` of `ViewFlipper`

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoStart="false"
    android:flipInterval="700"
    android:id="@+id/heartThrob"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

 >

     <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/small"
    android:id="@+id/heartOne"

     />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/big" 
    android:id="@+id/heartTwo"
 />


</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: There is an answer that can help you here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20636688/3111573

Answer (score 0):

Rite now i have set the `ViewFlipper` property  `android:keepScreenOn` to `true` so that the screen remain `ON` , but i am still waiting for some better answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue if I use viewFlipper's startFlipping with setFlipInterval methods. So I've solved this by using a handler to animate viewFlipper.

By the way, this problem occurs on Galaxy Nexus 4.0.1 but not on Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2.

I hope this part of my code helps you.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable autoSwipeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        moveLeft();
    }
};


private void moveLeft() {
    if (mViewFlipper != null && mViewFlipper.getChildCount() > 1) {
        mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(animLeftIn);
        mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(animLeftOut);

        mViewFlipper.showNext();

        startAutoCycle();           
    }
}

private void startAutoCycle() {
    if (mViewFlipper.getChildCount() > 1) {

        if (autoCycleInterval <= 0) {
            autoCycleInterval = 5000;           
        }

        handler.removeCallbacks(autoSwipeRunnable);
        handler.postDelayed(autoSwipeRunnable, autoCycleInterval);          
    }
}
```