# ViewFlipper does not restart flipping if Screen Lock is set to None

Tags: android

I found the same issue on [ViewFlipper does not restart flipping if Screen Lock is set to None](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38298):

A cool feature of the ViewFlipper widget is that it automatically stop flipping when the screen goes off, and restart flipping if it goes on.

Unfortunately, if no screen lock is set (Settings > Security > Screen Lock > None) the Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT is never broadcasted to system, and ViewFlipper cannot be restarted (ever).

Possible fixes are:

a) restart ViewFlipper flipping on ACTION_SCREEN_ON rather than ACTION_USER_PRESENT.
b) broadcast ACTION_USER_PRESENT if no screen lock is set and screen goes on.

Steps to reproduce the bug:

- Set Screen Lock to None in system settings.
- Start an app using a ViewFlipper.
- Set the screen off (quick press on power)
- Set the screen on (quick press on power)

Result: the ViewFlipper is no more animated

`Expected result: the ViewFlipper must be animated again.`

It seems that this issue hasn't been solved. I wanna fix it in my own app. is there any ways?

I tried to solve it. I sent the broadcaster `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` in my code. But it throw Exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT from pid=XXX, uid=XXX
```

Then I checked the source code found these broadcasters are only used by system. Failed.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this, it should work:

- Remove every startFlipping() or stopFlipping() or setAutoStart() or setFlipInterval() in your activity.
- Now add this to your activity:

Code:

```
private boolean isStarted = false;

private void runFlipper() {
    if (isStarted == false) {
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(42);
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 3000);
        isStarted = true;
    }
}

private void stopFlipper() {
    mHandler.removeMessages(42);
    isStarted = false;
}

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 42) {
            Log.d("ImageFlipper", "Next picture...");
            viewFlipper.showNext();
            msg = obtainMessage(42);
            sendMessageDelayed(msg, 3000);
        }
    }
};
```

("viewFlipper" is viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);)

- In the activity's onResume(), call runFlipper().
- In the activity's onPause(), call stopFlipper().

If it works, don't forget to clean the code ;)

```
private static final int DELAY_MSG = 42;
private static final int DELAY = 3000;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks for the answer. I'd much rather the API did what it was supposed to, but in Android we sometimes have to wave the white flag and write a nice hack if we want the app to get finished.

Answer (score 1):

ViewFlipper does not restart flipping if Screen Lock is set to None. This problem need to resolve by android frameworks.